# Obtain increment value in a non-numeric array loop/

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, collections

It's easy to obtain the current loop iteration's count when looping over a sequential numeric array.

```
(1..5)each do |num|
  @output[num] = num
end
```

But what if I need to loop on a collection of objects (that aren't sequential numeric collections), how do I obtain the increment value of the loop?

```
@objects.each do |obj|
  @output[obj] = obj.name
end
```

Obviously, the index is invalid. What is the ruby way to do what is clearly intended here (obtain an explicit numeric integer corresponding to the count of the loop cycle?

Comment: Does each_with_index do what you are looking for? http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index

Comment: yes! please answer and i'll accept

Comment: Do you want just `@objects.each { |obj| @output << obj.name }`?  Then `@output[i]` equals `@object[i].name`.  This can also be written `@object = @objects.map { |obj| obj.name }`. In any event, you don't need an index.

Comment: ooo `.map` creates a new array. So when I later use that array in, say another loop, that too can loop through them to access the values without an index in that loop too, right?

Comment: I did this: `@items.map do |i|
          if (i.name == some_condition)
            "voted"
          else
            ""
          end` This would give me an array containing the values of `"voted"` or `""` for the number of items in the @items enum, right?

Comment: I'll address your comments tomorrow if no one else has done so. Note that I was not notified that you left comments, because you did not include my SO @username. It was only chance that I saw them.

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is "yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) method. It iterates over the elements of the collection giving you both the item and the index. It works on unordered enumerations too, although the order might be inconsistent.